# Poner las letras abajo de cada radio

Tags: css

necesito poner las letras debajo de cada radio, pero no lo logro

```css
body {
  background-color: #47d1da;
  color: white;
  font: normal 500% Helvetica,Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: .0625em solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: inherit;
  height: 1em;
  outline: none;
  width: 1em;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  &:checked {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .1875em #47d1da;
    -webkit-transition: background .15s, box-shadow .1s; 
    transition: background .15s, box-shadow .1s; 
  }
}

strong {
  display: block;
  font-size: .5em;
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<strong>Pure CSS radio buttons</strong>
<input type="radio" name="group" /> radio 1
<input type="radio" name="group" checked /> radio 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: #47d1da;
  color: white;
  font: normal 500% Helvetica,Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: .0625em solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: inherit;
  height: 1em;
  outline: none;
  width: 1em;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  &:checked {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .1875em #47d1da;
    -webkit-transition: background .15s, box-shadow .1s; 
    transition: background .15s, box-shadow .1s; 
  }
}

strong {
  display: block;
  font-size: .5em;
  line-height: 3em;
}

.grupo {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<strong>Pure CSS radio buttons</strong>
<div class="grupo">
<input type="radio" name="group" />
<label>radio 1</label>
</div>
<div class="grupo">
<input type="radio" name="group" checked />
<label>radio 2</label
</div>
```

Se podría solucionar tan fácilmente como envolviendo el texto en un `<p>` ya que de manera inherente tienen la propiedad de ocupar el 100% de lo que ocupe su **padre** por lo que de esa manera no podría compartir el `<input>` línea con el texto, pero ya que estoy, te propongo una solución que estructuralmente y semánticamente es más correcta.

El `<label>` es la etiqueta que acompaña a los `<input>` en caso de que necesitemos otorgarles información extra. Al darle a estos un `float` y un `width: 100%;` les estamos diciendo que ocupen el 100% del espacio que ocupe su padre, consiguiendo lo mismo que con la solución del `<p>` que comenté más arriba.

También envolví en un `<div>` cada grupo de `<label>` + `<input>` para recalcar que ambos van juntos.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de lograrlo es añadiendo saltos de línea `<br/>` si no tienes que aplicar ningún estilo extra es lo más sencillo a realizar

```css
body {
  background-color: #47d1da;
  color: white;
  font: normal 500% Helvetica,Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: .0625em solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: inherit;
  height: 1em;
  outline: none;
  width: 1em;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  &:checked {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .1875em #47d1da;
    -webkit-transition: background .15s, box-shadow .1s; 
    transition: background .15s, box-shadow .1s; 
  }
}

strong {
  display: block;
  font-size: .5em;
  line-height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<strong>Pure CSS radio buttons</strong>
<input type="radio" name="group" />
<br/> 
radio 1
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group" checked />
<br/>
 radio 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ambos resultados que te han dado solucionan tu problema, pero, como en tú código los radio están en la misma línea, te dejo mi solución que implicaría modificar un poco el html.

Por funcionalidad, que al darle al texto se marque también el radio, pondría el texto en un `label` y aplicaría el estilo a eso. Si no se pudiera, puedes usar las opciones que ya te han dado junto con la siguiente:

Cada conjunto de `label` y `radio` los metería en un elemento (en mi caso un `span`) con una clase para afectar a todos y aplicaría estilos sobre ella.

```
.form-radio {
   display: inline-block; 
   width: 50%; 
   box-sizing: border-box; 
   float: left; 
}
```

Así quedaría el código: (Ten en cuenta que he sacado el `input:checked` de la etiqueta `input` para que el snippet lo reconozca, si vas a utilizar otro lenguaje que no sea `css` puro, modifica eso)

```css
body {
  background-color: #47d1da;
  color: white;
  font: normal 500% Helvetica,Arial;
  text-align: center;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: .0625em solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font: inherit;
  height: 1em;
  outline: none;
  width: 1em;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;

}

 input[type="radio"]:checked {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .1875em #47d1da;
    -webkit-transition: background .15s, box-shadow .1s; 
    transition: background .15s, box-shadow .1s; 
  }

strong {
  display: block;
  font-size: .5em;
  line-height: 3em;
}

label {
display: block;
}

.form-radio {
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<strong>Pure CSS radio buttons</strong>
<span class="form-radio"><input type="radio" name="group" id="radio1" /> <label for="radio1">radio 1</label></span>
<span class="form-radio"><input type="radio" name="group" id="radio2" checked /> <label for="radio2">radio 2</label></span>
```